# Android: Retrieving and Displaying all photos from phone, including gallery and downloads?

Tags: android, photos

Does anyone happen to know of a tutorial that goes over this? It seems like it would be a fairly common interest, I've seen a number of things that are related, but nothing that specifically addresses it recently.

For example, the facebook android app performs exactly this when you click the photo button in the bottom bar.

I would like to retrieve all photos in downloads and the gallery regardless of whether the phone has an sdcard.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display existing photos for the user choose, here's what I do:

```
private static final int _GALLERY_PHOTO_REQUEST = 2;
        ...
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a Photo"), _GALLERY_PHOTO_REQUEST);
```

Then, I do this (once the user selects or dismisses the photo picker):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    // I'm using an if{} block here, if you have multiple resultCodes to check, then use a switch{} block.
    if (Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode)
    {
        if (requestCode == _GALLERY_PHOTO_REQUEST)
        {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            // Do something with the chosen photo, such as my custom method to process the photo
            processPhoto(uri);
        }
        else
        {
            default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        String msg = String.format(Locale.US, "Activity resultCode was not OK, it was %d, and requestCode is %d", resultCode, requestCode);
        Log.w("MyTag", msg);
    }
}
```